# Unity online board game different view for different player

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am kind of new to Unity in general, i am building a 2 player online board game using PUN 2. where players camera opposite to each other. i rotate the Game Board 180 degree for 2nd player. I have encountered a problem with the changing position. my approach to this problem is not correct to rotate 180 degree.

Comment: Could you add some explanation about what problem you saw and how it differed from what you expected? Also some code might help us help you :)

Comment: why not using a different camera for the second player and don't rotate the whole board at all?

Comment: thanks derHugo, i rotate the camera 180 degree for 2nd player and my problem is solve.